# VBA finding and formatting methods with 2 different data bases

Tags: database, vba, find, compare

I have 2 differently formatted databases(drakev_db, kingdom_db) which common values. I have to compare the 2 databases, and in match case to get the UWI code from drakev_db and put it to the kingdom_db.

The problems are: 
1. the only common keys are the coordinates, which ones doesn't match 100%--I've checked the first 7 characters
2. the "well names" and "well numbers" are formatted differently, with accents, with 0025 or 025 number formats
3. I have 3000 datas with UWI codes what I have to compare to 9000 datas, so I don't want to do manually

What I realized until now:
-to get the first X coordinate from drakev_db, search for it--save the matched cells row number
-same with Y coordinate from drakev_db
-if there are 2 matches, and the X and Y coordinates row number (k and m) are equals, then I put the data in merged_db

Whit this method I have been found 955 matches, but there are a lot of more.
My questions are:

1. What kind of searching method should I use?
2. What can I do when I have no common keys?
3. How can I format the names to be able to compare with each other?

Any ideeas, scripts? :)

Note: this is my 3rd macro, and first post, sorry for amateur formatting-

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

            Set king = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("kingdom_db")
            Set drakev = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("drakev1_db")
            Set merged = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("merged_db")
            Set uwi = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("uwi_gen")

               merged.Range("a3:j5000").Delete
               uwi.Range("a3:e10000").Delete

                     nrow = 2
                     nrow2 = 2
                     uwinb = 520000000231#

                For y = 4 To 9450

                                    cell = king.Cells(y, 7).Value
                                    mit = Left$(cell, 7)
                                    mymatch = Array(mit)

                                    cell2 = king.Cells(y, 8).Value
                                    mit2 = Left$(cell2, 7)
                                    mymatch2 = Array(mit2)

                        With Sheets("drakev1_db").Range("p3:p5430")

                        For i = LBound(mymatch) To UBound(mymatch)
                             Set res = Nothing
                             Set res = .Find(What:=mymatch, _
                                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.count), _
                                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=False)

                                If res Is Nothing Then
                                                  Else: k = res.Row
                                End If
                        Next i
                        End With


                           With Sheets("drakev1_db").Range("q3:q5430")

                           For l = LBound(mymatch2) To UBound(mymatch2)
                                Set res2 = Nothing
                                Set res2 = .Find(What:=mymatch2, _
                                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.count), _
                                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                            MatchCase:=False)

                                 If res2 Is Nothing Then
                                                    Else: m = res2.Row
                                 End If
                            Next l
                            End With

                                     If res Is Nothing And res2 Is Nothing Then
                                                        nrow2 = nrow2 + 1
                                                        uwinb = uwinb + 1
                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 1).Value = king.Cells(y, 1).Value
                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 2).Value = king.Cells(y, 2).Value
                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 3).Value = king.Cells(y, 7).Value
                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 4).Value = king.Cells(y, 8).Value

                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 5).Value = uwinb

                                        ElseIf res Is Nothing Or res2 Is Nothing Then
                                                         nrow2 = nrow2 + 1
                                                        uwinb = uwinb + 1
                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 1).Value = king.Cells(y, 1).Value
                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 2).Value = king.Cells(y, 2).Value
                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 3).Value = king.Cells(y, 7).Value
                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 4).Value = king.Cells(y, 8).Value

                                                         uwi.Cells(nrow2, 5).Value = uwinb

                                       ElseIf Not k = m Then

                                       Else: talalat = k
                                              nrow = nrow + 1

                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 1).Value = king.Cells(y, 1).Value
                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 2).Value = king.Cells(y, 2).Value
                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 3).Value = king.Cells(y, 6).Value
                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 4).Value = king.Cells(y, 7).Value
                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 5).Value = king.Cells(y, 8).Value
                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 7).Value = drakev.Cells(talalat, 4).Value
                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 8).Value = drakev.Cells(talalat, 3).Value
                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 9).Value = drakev.Cells(talalat, 16).Value
                                                  merged.Cells(nrow, 10).Value = drakev.Cells(talalat, 17).Value


                                                End If

                    Next
                                                             merged.Activate
                                                            ActiveSheet.Range("h3:h10000").Select

                                                            Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

                                                            uwi.Activate
                                                            ActiveSheet.Range("e3:e10000").Select
                                                            Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

                                                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("merged_db").Activate

            If Not k = "" Then MsgBox "good job@"
            End Sub
```

Comment: [![Drakev_db][1]][1]
[![King_db][2]][2]
[![the result:merged_db][3]][3]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DGXpF.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/m1pNK.jpg
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hsF0M.jpg